# I can't see JavaFX options nor create new JavaFX project

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I installed [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) by adding it as a software site. My eclipse is 4.4, my Java is 8.0. When I create a new project, there is no *JavaFX>JavaFX* Application option.

There's also no JavaFX in the popup menu. However, in preferences, i can see a JavaFX setting for my scenebuilder.

Is something wrong or do I have to reinstall e(fx)clipse? Can we fix it without reinstalling ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'adding it as a software site'? Once you have done that you have to work with the site and install what you want from it.

Comment: did you follow this guide fully?http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

Comment: Not sure but only adding the software site is not enough what feature of e(fx)clipse did you install to your IDE? Also make sure your Eclipse is running with JDK8 - you can check that in the About-Dialog.

if you still have problems please post at the e(fx)clipse forum at Eclipse.org (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/)